# Working out custom font name

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having trouble getting a font to display. ([Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand))

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>bebas.ttf</string>
    <string>Quicksand_Bold.ttf</string>
    <string>Quicksand_Book.ttf</string>
</array>
```

I have tried various ways to call it "Quicksand", "Quicksand Bold", "Quicksand-Bold" and so on..

```
UILabel *theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 890, 60)];
theLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Quicksand-Bold" size:50];
theLabel.text = @"Label Text";
```

Is there an easy way to find the name I should use? In Font Book it is naming it "Quicksand Bold Regular", which also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late to respond, but I have solved it.

I had simply forgotten to add the files to the Bundle Resources list.

[image: Copy Bundle Resources]

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the name of the font file and the name of the font in the system are different. You should print the names of all fonts with `NSLog` and see what name the system uses.

```
NSFontManager* fm =[NSFontManager sharedFontManager]
NSLog(@"%@", [fm availableFonts]);
```

I wrote this up in a tutorial on my blog about adding fonts to applications: [How to add fonts to iOS and OSX applications.](http://riveroften.com/how-to-add-fonts-to-ios-and-osx-applications/)

Comment: That is returning the font name as "QuicksandBold-Regular", which is not working.

Comment: I found the best way to workout the current fonts was to use [UIFont familyNames], then [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Font Name"]